# How to handle HTTPS get request from browser using Socket's inputstream

Tags: java, sockets, https, get

I am writing a simple HTTP proxy server. I can handle **HTTP GET** requests from browser. However, I am having problems with handling **HTTPS GET** requests.
I have a parser for parsing HTTP GET requests and I know how HTTP GET request looks like:

> GET /Path HTTP/1.1 (\r\n)
>
> Headers (key:value) (\r\n)
>
> ....
>
> (\r\n\r\n)

But I have no idea how **HTTPS GET** looks like, and how to parse it.
When HTTPS request is fired from browser my proxy is getting weird characters. And I am sure this is because of encryption. But how can I handle Secured requests from browser using just Java's Socket class

```
try ( BufferedReader inputStream = 
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
      OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream(); ) { 
   ....
}
```

Comment: Encryption is performed on presentation level, which is higher than transport level on which you operate.

Answer (score 2):

For `HTTPS` connections, all you can do is to forward the data you receive. That data is encrypted, and only the destination server can decrypt it.

If you want to read that requests too, you will need to speak `SSL`/`TLS`, which is the underlying protocol. Also, you will need a certificate, which, unless signed by a *Certification Authority* and valid for the requested domain, will prevent browsers from displaying the content, as they do not trust the certificate.

Comment: So How can I find out whether it is HTTPS, because you know I cannot parse inputStream if it is encrypted, I mean before forwarding you should know whether it is simple socket or secure one. If the latter is the case, I should create secure socket from Factory, and get requested servers certificate, but without parsing inputStream how I can get requested server's hostname, or IP

Comment: @Humoyun based on port, HTTP traffic uses port `80` and HTTPS `443`.

Comment: of course, :) so simple solution, woe for me, How I could not come up with this, anyway thank you